# Automapper and request specific resources

Tags: unity-container, automapper

I'm considering automapper for an asp mvc intranet app I am writing. My controllers are currently created using Unity dependency injection, where each container gets dependencies unique to the request.

I need to know if automapper can be made to use a request specific resource ICountryRepository to look up an object, like so....

```
domainObject.Country = CountryRepository.Load(viewModelObject.CountryCode);
```

Answer (score 4):

Couple of options here. One is to do a custom resolver:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CountryCodeResolver>())
```

Then your resolver would be (assuming CountryCode is a string. Could be a string, whatever):

```
public class CountryCodeResolver : ValueResolver<string, Country> {
    private readonly ICountryRepository _repository;

    public CountryCodeResolver(ICountryRepository repository) {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    protected override Country ResolveCore(string source) {
        return _repository.Load(source);
    }
}
```

Finally, you'll need to hook in Unity to AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => myUnityContainer.Resolve(type));

    // Other AutoMapper configuration here...
});
```

Where "myUnityContainer" is your configured Unity container. A custom resolver defines a mapping between one member and another. We often define a global type converter for all string -> Country mappings, so that I don't need to configure every single member. It looks like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => myUnityContainer.Resolve(type));

    cfg.CreateMap<string, Country>().ConvertUsing<StringToCountryConverter>();

    // Other AutoMapper configuration here...
});
```

Then the converter is:

```
public class StringToCountryConverter : TypeConverter<string, Country> {
    private readonly ICountryRepository _repository;

    public CountryCodeResolver(ICountryRepository repository) {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    protected override Country ConvertCore(string source) {
        return _repository.Load(source);
    }
}
```

In a custom type converter, you wouldn't need to do any member-specific mapping. Any time AutoMapper sees a string -> Country conversion, it uses the above type converter.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer!  Unfortunately I won't have a reference to the container at the point of configuring the automapper, as the container will be a child-container created by the master container at the point a request is received.